# Problem to deploy simplest Spring Cloud Function application on AWS Lambda using docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I having a problem deploying the simplest Spring Cloud Function application to AWS Lambda using a docker image.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GraalvmFuncExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GraalvmFuncExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Mono<MyRequest>, Mono<MyResponse>> transform() {
        return req -> {
            return req.flatMap(r -> Mono.just(MyResponse.builder().name(r.getName().toUpperCase()).build()));
        };
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>vlad.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>graalvm-func-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>graalvm-func-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <start-class>com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-parent</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The error I get:

```
14:07:40.192 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.utils.FunctionClassUtils -- Main class: class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)
2023-08-12T14:07:42.761Z  INFO 9 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.a.aws.CustomRuntimeInitializer   : AWS Handler: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker
2023-08-12T14:07:42.824Z  INFO 9 --- [           main] c.a.s.l.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda     : Starting AWSLambda v2.1.1 using Java 17.0.3 with PID 9 (/var/runtime/lib/aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.1.1.jar started by sbx_user1051 in /)
2023-08-12T14:07:42.826Z  INFO 9 --- [           main] c.a.s.l.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-12T14:07:43.969Z  INFO 9 --- [           main] c.a.s.l.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda     : Started AWSLambda in 2.857 seconds (process running for 4.037)
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionCatalog' available: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionCatalog' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker.start(FunctionInvoker.java:109)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:71)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:79)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
START RequestId: 6368b3eb-605f-490b-bc2e-f74972623968 Version: $LATEST
2023-08-12T14:08:35.442Z 6368b3eb-605f-490b-bc2e-f74972623968 Task timed out after 3.09 seconds
```

Any idea why I get the "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionCatalog' available: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" on cloud.
It works just fine on my local non-cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your pom has **spring-cloud-function-parent** which does not look right, below a [regular](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/master/cloud-functional-bean/pom.xml) pom for cloud function

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

here is [AWS spring cloud example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-aws/pom.xml) pom dependencies

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-lambda-events.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

in your case, can you try to change your dependencies like below

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

for full pom please [check](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.1.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-function).

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @ozkanpakdil, the parent always has to be

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>. . .whatever boot version you want to use . . .</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and then let s-cloud manager the dependency versions for you

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```